# Symfony2 multiple @template in a controller

Tags: templates, symfony, controller, twig

I am very new to symfony2 and trying very hard for past few days to figure out a problem. My controller is

```
<?php

namespace Myname\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/{type}/{nav}", defaults={"nav"="nil"})
     * @Template("MyBundle::index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction($type, $nav)
    {
        return array('type' => $type, 'nav' => $nav);

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/myLink/accounts", name="page_accounts")
     * @Template("MyBundle::accounts.html.twig")
     */
    public function accountsAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyBundle::accounts.html.twig');
    }
}
```

But the problem I am facing is, which ever link I am trying to use, it is using the first defined template and the second template is never rendered. But if I remove the first template from the code, the second one is working perfectly. Any comments will be really great as I am stuck for last 4 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you mind also posting how you call those actions?
Also the URL that is called, calling each action.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your issue.  However, I think there are some issues with your controller and how you are using the @Template annotation.

First, if you are following the default conventions, then you don't even need to specify the template to use.  Also, when using the @Template annotation, you are supposed to return an array.

If none of this helps or is related, could you please clarify some more?

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/{type}/{nav}", defaults={"nav"="nil"})
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexAction($type, $nav)
    {
        return array('type' => $type, 'nav' => $nav);

    }

    /**
     * @Route("/myLink/accounts", name="page_accounts")
     * @Template
     */
    public function accountsAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```